# How would I do a two finger drag with javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, css, ios

I'm trying to create the ability to drag a div when there are two fingers placed on it.

I've bound the div to the touchstart and touchmove events. I'm just not sure how to write the functions.

Something like `if event.originalEvent.targetTouches.length => 2` set starting X and Y.

Do I average the two fingers positions? Then apply css transforms with the data? How do I pull it out of the flow of the DOM, static positioning?

Any examples would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CoffeeScript, I also edited it to use globals for the purpose of generalizing. I'm not using global variables.

```
    $('#div').bind 'touchstart', touchstart
    $('#div').bind 'touchmove', touchmove

    touchstart: (event) =>
        if event.originalEvent.touches.length >= 2

            x = 0
            y = 0

            for touch in event.originalEvent.touches
                x += touch.screenX
                y += touch.screenY

            window.startx = x/event.originalEvent.touches.length
            window.starty = y/event.originalEvent.touches.length

    touchmove: (event) =>
        if event.originalEvent.touches.length >= 2

            x = 0
            y = 0

            for touch in event.originalEvent.touches
                x += touch.screenX
                y += touch.screenY

            movex = (x/event.originalEvent.touches.length) - @startx
            movey = (y/event.originalEvent.touches.length) - @starty

            newx = $('#div').offset().left + movex
            newy = $('#div').offset().top + movey

            $('#div').offset({top: newy, left: newx})

            window.startx = x/event.originalEvent.touches.length
            window.starty = y/event.originalEvent.touches.length
```