# Pinch or mousewheel to zoom

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need the functionality like this demo: http://preview.codecanyon.net/item/pinch-zoomer-jquery-plugin/full_screen_preview/6623080

In desktops, the image can be zoomed in/out by the mouse wheel and on touch screen devices, 2 fingers gestures can be used to zoom in/out.

I would use the library mentioned, but $6 seems a bit too much. I did find some other open-source libraries but they don't have both the features.

I am building a static site that dynamically (using javascript) loads a single image.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the desired result you can use the `onmousewheel` event and, when triggered, set it to change the `transform: scale(1, 1)` of the image based on the:

- `e.wheelDelta` (All browsers except Firefox and Opera) and
- `e.detail` (For Firefox and Opera).

When you scroll down `e.wheelDelta` and `e.detail` are negative valuesand when you scroll up the are positive.

**Example**:

```
var image = your image id;
image.onmousewheel = function(e) {
    var delta = e.detail || e.wheelDelta;
    image.style.transform = (delta > 0) ? "scale(2, 2)" : "scale(0.5, 0.5)";
}
```

You can of course create a more complex function by modifying the `scale` based on the exact `delta` value.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [touchy](https://github.com/HotStudio/touchy#touchy-pinch) library

simply call an event on the image and based on received scale parameters, change the scale of image in callback as well.

```
$('#my_div').bind('touchy-pinch', handleTouchyPinch);
```

and for implementing 2 finger drag, touch event contains a property `touches`

```
$elem.on('touchstart', function (e) {
    if (e.touches.length > 1)
        // your rocking code here...
});
```

also checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7926605/how-would-i-do-a-two-finger-drag-with-javascript-jquery)